# Query Same Table Distinct Records

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

All,

I have the following query that I have been trying to figure how to make work for the better part of a day.  It returns no records when I run it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT op.OperationID
FROM ProductionOperations op
LEFT JOIN ProductionOperations op1 ON (op.OperationID = op1.OperationID)
WHERE op1.ID Is Null;
```

I know it isn't correct and SQL isn't in my wheelhouse and I need someone way smarter than me to help.  I have a table, ProductionOperations, that has an OperationID column and a OperationComplete {0,1} column.  The table could have multiple records with the same Operation ID number if the operation fails (0) to complete when the operation is tried.  It may take 3 or 4 tries before the operation completes.  Sometimes it may not complete all together.  In the end I want to get the count of distinct operations that failed, not a count of every operation that failed (0).

This is what the table could look like:
[pic of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMhv2.jpg)

I need to count the number of operations completed, which would be 4 in the preceding table and the count for the number of operations that did not complete, which would be 2.  Any help would be appreciated.  Note, the table is just an example and not the actual table I am working with.  Can't share due to IP.

Thanks

Comment: Have you attempted anything???

Comment: It would be great if you could provide the sample table data in proper columns instead, and also show us the expected result.

Comment: Which dbms?  Sample input?  Expected output?  Table structure?  Please read this guide.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Seems like you just need a subquery: SELECT OperationMax, COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT OperationID, MAX(OperationComplete) AS OperationMax FROM ProductionOperations GROUP BY OperationID) AS X GROUP BY OperationMax

Comment: *the number of operations completed, which would be 3...* are you sure? There are 4 in your sample data. Also tag your question with the database that you use: MySql, SQL Server, Oracle?

Comment: Yeah, 4 is correct.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two levels of aggregation. First get the maximum of `operationcompleted` for each operation. That would be `1` for completed operations and `0` for not completed operations. Then use conditional aggregation to count the `1`s and `0`s to get the counts.

```
SELECT count(CASE
               WHEN operationcomplete = 1 THEN
                 1
             END) completed_operations,
       count(CASE
               WHEN operationcomplete = 0 THEN
                 1
             END) not_completed_operations
       FROM (SELECT operationid,
                    max(operationcomplete) operationcomplete
                    FROM elbat
                    GROUP BY operationid) x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 levels of aggregation:

```
select 
  iif(t.MaxOperationComplete = 1, 'Completed', 'Failed') as OperationStatus,
  count(*) as counter
from (  
  select OperationID, max(OperationComplete) as MaxOperationComplete
  from ProductionOperations 
  group by OperationID
) as t  
group by t.MaxOperationComplete
```

Results:

```
OperationStatus counter
Failed          2
Completed       4
```

Or if you want the results in 1 row:

```
select 
  -sum(t.MaxOperationComplete = 0) as Failed,  
  -sum(t.MaxOperationComplete = 1) as Completed
from (  
  select OperationID, max(OperationComplete) as MaxOperationComplete
  from ProductionOperations 
  group by OperationID
) as t
```

Results:

```
Failed  Completed
2       4
```